How to Customize or Remove Specific Routes Created by AddIdentityApiEndpoints in .NET 8?
I am working with .NET 8 and trying to use AddIdentityApiEndpoints to set up authentication for my Web API. However, I am facing a problem where I don't know exactly how to remove some of the routes created by this method that I don't need. Additionally, I would like to control specific routes under certain conditions that I have in mind.
Is there a way to customize, remove, or manage these routes more effectively? Any guidance or examples would be highly appreciated.
I have tried various approaches, including attempting to filter out some of the routes, but none of them worked effectively.


is there a way to customize, remove, or manage these routes more
effectively?

There is no custom tool for implementing custom IdentityApiEndpoints nodes at present. So, it is not possible to customize the terminal nodes in IdentityApiEndpoints, but you can implement custom routing endpoints through MapMethods, and then protect the endpoints through RequireAuthorization Method.
Such as:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello, World!");
app.MapGet("/secret", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity?.Name}. My secret")
    .RequireAuthorization();

app.Run();

For more information, please refer to this link.
In addition, if you do not want to use the relevant IdentityApiEndpoints,want to implement custom routing and related authentication in a more free way, you can also implement authentication through traditional routing by creating a controller and configuring relevant authentication methods and services.
